# Infinite cycle over a range starting at a particular number

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

Say I have a range:

```
r = range(1, 6)
```

Using this range, I want to cycle infinitely and yield the numbers as they come:

```
for i in cycle(r):
    yield(i)
```

This would correctly produce values of:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, ...
```

However, I sometimes want to start the yielding from a specific value but continue on with the range as it's defined. That is, if I want to start at `3`, the sequence would be:

```
3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

Is there a way to do this with a combination of `range` and `cycle` (or some other way)?

Comment: Did you look into [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)?

Comment: you could just call `next` twice and then start looking at the results?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How will that ever produce 1 or 2 in the range if I keep dropping those every time they are encountered??

Comment: @JasonStein I want this to work for an arbitrary start point, obviously...

Comment: *"if I keep dropping those every time they are encountered"* - ...did you read what the docs say it *does*?

Comment: Simple way would be to use `itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(r), 2, None)`

Comment: @mart1n the most readable way is to use `islice` as @AChampion suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) until you reach the first value you want to emit:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, dropwhile
>>> iterable = dropwhile(lambda x: x < 3, cycle(range(1, 6)))
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print(next(iterable))
...
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
```

Per the docs (emphasis mine):

> Make an iterator that drops elements from the iterable as long as the
>   predicate is true; **afterwards, returns every element**.

The `predicate` only takes effect until the first value for which it evaluates false-y.

Comment: Ohhh! You are very right! When I read through the docs, I understood it as drop while the value **always** evaluates to Truthy. Thanks, great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Since `cycle` starts from the beginning of the iterator given to it, give it an iterator (a sequence in this case) that starts where you want:

```
r = tuple(range(3,6)) + tuple(range(1,3))
```

The `1` above is the lowest value to repeat, the `6` is one more than the highest value, and the `3` used twice is the starting value. It should be clear how to generalize this to other cases.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to chain two ranges together and pass the chain to `cycle`.

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

def shift_cycle(lo, start, stop):
    return cycle(chain(range(start, stop), range(lo, start)))

for t in zip(range(12), shift_cycle(1, 3, 6)):
    print('{}: {}'.format(*t))
```

**output**

```
0: 3
1: 4
2: 5
3: 1
4: 2
5: 3
6: 4
7: 5
8: 1
9: 2
10: 3
11: 4
```

This approach has an advantage over `islice` or `dropwhile` if the `start` and `stop` args are large because it doesn't need to discard the unwanted initial items.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps unesthetic but practical? `sys.maxsize` being "practically infinite" for many purposes

```
import sys

r, n = 5, 3
cyc = (i%r + 1 for i in range(n, sys.maxsize))

next(cyc)
Out[106]: 4

next(cyc)
Out[107]: 5

next(cyc)
Out[108]: 1

next(cyc)
Out[109]: 2

next(cyc)
Out[110]: 3

next(cyc)
Out[111]: 4

next(cyc)
Out[112]: 5

next(cyc)
Out[113]: 1
```

`sys.maxsize*1e-9/3600/24/365
Out[117]: 292.471208677536`

that's years at 1 ns per request - on a 64 bit system

but of course it runs a bit slower

```
timeit.timeit('next(cyc)','r, n = 5, 3; cyc = (i%r + 1 for i in range(n, sys.maxsize))')
Out[126]: 0.2556792100261305
```

the modulo takes more time as requests keeps upping `i`

but that doesn't seem to be the big time sink

```
timeit.timeit('max%5', 'max=sys.maxsize')

Out[120]: 0.07545763840474251

timeit.timeit('1111%5')
Out[122]: 0.01156394737682831

timeit.timeit('111%5')
Out[123]: 0.011720469965638358
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the `islice` function

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
offset = 2
r = range(1, 6)
generator = islice(cycle(r), offset, None)
```